# Regex for identifying a sentence

Tags: regex, expression

Below is my sample line :
"lonelyplanet" || **"Do you agree? RT @wheresandynow: The World's Rudest Nations For Travelers - Forbes http://t.co/0Fcq7B6r #forbeslife #lp"** || "en" || "Tue, 03 Apr 2012 17:02:23 +0000" || NH || South Tamworth

I want to extract only those lines which are written in bold letters.

I tried (\|)(\|)\s\"(.*?)+\" but it extracts "en" and
 "Tue, 03 Apr 2012 17:02:23 +0000" in addition to the required one.

Please help..

Comment: Is your target sentence always in the second column as delimited by `||`? That would eliminate the need for using a regex at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `/(?<=\|\|)[^|]+/`

```
'"lonelyplanet" || "Do you agree? RT @wheresandynow: The World\'s Rudest Nations For Travelers - Forbes http://t.co/0Fcq7B6r #forbeslife #lp" || "en" || "Tue, 03 Apr 2012 17:02:23 +0000" || NH || South Tamworth' =~ /(?<=\|\|)[^|]+/
=> 17

$&
=> " \"Do you agree? RT @wheresandynow: The World's Rudest Nations For Travelers - Forbes http://t.co/0Fcq7B6r #forbeslife #lp\" "
```

Comment: BTW, you can use /(?<=[|]{2}).*?(?=[|]{2})+/ if you want to allow a single '|' within the sentence.

Comment: the above is ruby syntax. tested and work in ruby. what language are you using?

Comment: this regex should also work in perl/php. you can check here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: weird, this worked for me. maybe the problem is somewhere else? can you post the exact code you're using?